# Storing "String" as "TEXT" instead of "VarChar" in SQLite - WP8

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I'm storing my Data in local database using SQLite.
I've string typed few variables to store. Now, when I store that string variables, it is being stored as "VARCHAR" (as in the picture below).

> Picture 1

[image]

But I want to store those strings as "TEXT" type in SQLite. (as in the picture below)

> Picture 2

[image]

The class I'm using to store db is as below:

```
public class abc
{
    [SQLite.AutoIncrement, SQLite.PrimaryKey]
    public int _id { get; set; }
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
    public string d { get; set; }
    public string e { get; set; }
    public string f { get; set; }
    public string g { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }

}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `varchar` is `TEXT` in `SQLite` so u need not to worry !

Answer (score 9):

`varchar` is `TEXT` in `SQLite` so u need not to worry!

Internally the data is always stored as TEXT, so even if you create table with `VARCHAR(LEN)`, SQLite is going to follow the rules of `TEXT` data type

Comment: Thanks for reply but Its not like that. As i posted the image, there is a difference and that difference makes incompatibility issues with the database file created in other platform like android and ios

Comment: What incompatibility?

Comment: @CL
see, we have cross platform app for wp, android & iphone.
now we are sharing the common DB file made by SQLite in every platform.
In the question, Picture 1 is of the DB file created by WP and Picture 2 is of the DB file created by android.
now, when the DB file created by WP copied to android device, then the data isn't displaying on that device. that means VarChar(len) datatype creates issue. if we change VarChar(len) to TEXT type manually then it works..
same with iphone app.
p.s. sorry for long explanation..

Comment: SQLite itself does not distinguish between VARCHAR and TEXT.

Comment: @KevalLangalia Hi keval, so what was the conclusion? did `VARCHAR` worked for you or you changed it all to `TEXT` after all?

Comment: no.. not actually. I had to change the scenario I was working on. Except that, the problem will arise only if the scenario is of cross platform app, otherwise `VARCHAR` is `TEXT` itself.

Comment: You are wrong. Try to declare some column with `varchar`, then try to select `where yourcol = 'somevalue`. It will not work. You need `where CAST(yourcol AS text) = 'somevalue'` to work

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no difference between `Text` and `Varchar` data types in SQLite, but if you want to change it the way you want, do this:

If you are using `sqlite-net` (SQLite.cs & SQLiteAsync.cs) in your WP8.0 app, then go to **SQLite.cs** class and find the `SqlType` method (about line 1863). Then you can see `if (clrType == typeof(String))` statement. If you prefer `Text` data type then you can change `varchar` to `text` as you like.

Answer (score 0):

As to my knowledge, Text type accepts UTF-8 and special chars symbols, etc. Its  not the same with type Varchar.